# Table of Contents: add vertical space above chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, line-spacing

I am using Lyx and a custom  document class for my thesis. I initially had a problem with a long chapter title being hyphenated; I needed to have the TOC be ragged right for the title of chapter one in this sample. [image: hyphenated chapter name in toc]

First I tried to just add `\raggedright` just before `\tableofcontents`; no joy.

Next, I tried 

`\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}{\cftchapfont}{\raggedright}`

This changed the font and look of the toc but still didn't remove the hypenation![image: different look, problem unsolved]

Next I tried

```
\usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}    
\newtocstyle{raggedstyle}{%
      \settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
      \settocfeature{spaceafternumber}{17pt}
    }
    \usetocstyle{raggedstyle}
```

(Actually, even before modifying this code, I tried using `\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}`; the result was the same as above except that all of the indentations were lost.) I finally solved  the problem of removing the hyphenation; however, it also removed the spaces between the chapters. [image: problem solved but missing vertical spaces]

I have squandered enough time trying to fix this by myself. Please help!

Comment: try with `\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}`

Comment: instead of snippets, please try to post small blocks of code that demonstrate your problem and can be standalone compiled so someone can just copy/paste to troubleshoot for you.  you'll probably get more answers from this community this way : ).

Comment: The reason why certain packages might not work is because the document class probably already loads some packages dealing with the ToC. So, your attempt at loading some packages might not interface well/work at the point where you're trying to fix it. Could you point us to this "custom document class for your thesis?"

Comment: You can find the custom document class here. https://wiki.cites.illinois.edu/wiki/display/ECEThesisReview/LaTeX+Resources

Please note that I am using it in Lyx, so I had to convert the uiucecethesis09 class into a Lyx template.

Comment: @touhami: Thank you for your advice. I tried `\usetocstyle{standard} \settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}`. It did remove the hyphenation but changed the font and made the chapter titles bold. This will not pass thesis check.

Comment: As a quick fix, use \mbox{between} to prevent it from being hyphenated.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks so much. That was indeed a quick fix; however, on a later chapter, too much text was squeezed on the line and it pushed the page number to the right and out of alignment with the rest of the page numbers. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try \hfil \mbox{between} or perhaps \linebreak[3] between

Comment: @JohnKormylo: First off, thank you again for your help. `\hfil \mbox{}` resulted in no change. `\linebreak[3]` produced errors, so I used `\newline` instead. This worked for the TOC, however, it leaves two lines in my main document with only one word. This will not work either. Can I easily reduce the margin of the chapter title text in the toc? This will force the linebreak in the toc but not the main doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using tocloft changes the overall style unacceptably, you can use \mbox{} to prevent individual words from being hypenated and \sloppy to prevent the line from extending too far.  It is even possible to force a line break using \hbox to (at least for this setup).

Since the chapter title at the start of the chapter is already \raggedright, adding \sloppy does not seem to change it or generate an error message.

[image: toc hypenation]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a very long chapter title containing words like electromagnetic and particle.}
\chapter{This is a very long chapter title containing words like \mbox{electromagnetic} and particle.}
\chapter{\sloppy This is a very long chapter title containing words like \mbox{electromagnetic} and particle.}
\chapter{This is a very long chapter title containing words like \hbox to 2em{}\hspace{-2em}electromagnetic and particle.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! \sloppy didn't seem to process, so I tried your last suggestion, although I had to go to 5em in order to force the word to the next line. You are a gem. Thanks so much!